# NSURLConnection with Airplane Mode

Tags: ios, xcode

When using NSURLConnection is airplane mode the exact same as 'No Service'?

Currently airplane mode returns the error method fine. However when I have No Service, the data is returned as nil.

I have always thought they were the exact same. Is there anyway to test No Service without being in airplane mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried Network Link Conditioner?
It's an option you can add to iOS and Mac in developer mode that allows you to simulate different network conditions, like lossy networks, no service conditions etc...

There's a good intro [guide on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/) and, of course, docs on Apples developer portal.